# Cassandra Prepared Statements broken after schema migration

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm preparing statements in the constructor of my repository class, like this

```java
PreparedStatement getStatement = cqlSession.prepare(selectFrom("the_table")
.all()
.whereColumn("the_key").isEqualTo(bindMarker())
.build());
```

I later bind it to a BoundStatement and read the results like this

```java
String someColumn = row.isNull("some_column") ? null : row.getString("some_column")
```

During runtime I run an alter on the table, adding a column. Something I expected would work since I query for columns only by name. However, it seems that the driver internally has mapped the column names to column indexes which are now all broken.

Is this expected? It severely limits what can be done in run time.

Am I missing something that would have forced a re-prepare of a statement on schema change?

Can I intercept it and re-prepare manually?

I'm running spring boot 2.5.9 and the driver version 4.11.3
The cassandra cluster runs version 3.11.10

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the question!

Your symptoms sound similar to the behaviours described in [CASSANDRA-10786](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10786).  If you're dealing with a version before Cassandra 4.0 this could very well be what's going on.

Does the description in that issue match up with what you're seeing?

Comment: it does sound similar but I can't promise it's the same cause internally. I'm on cassandra 3.7.x so this wouldn't be fixed

Comment: I was wrong, it's 3.11.10

Answer (score 1):

To add to @absurdfarce's answer, Cassandra 3.7 is a very old release. In fact, it was released all the way back to early 2016.

There were several important fixes to prepared statements since then. Although  a quick browse of those fixes don't seem to be directly related to the issue you reported, they are significant nonetheless.

Additionally there were several fixes to schema migration/propagation in the last 6 years. Again, they don't directly relate to your problem and I'm ordinarily loathe to push for an upgrade but I think 6 years' worth of fixes between C* 3.7 to 3.11.latest merits it. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong on the version of cassandra, it's version 3.11.10